# json objects = respecive html divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

What is the exact way(javascript/jquery) to point Objects created in external JSON file to point and populate to their corresponding html divs. I am posting the complete code for html and JSON. Also refer to the image to get a clear idea of where the divs are and what data they hold.Also this should happen at HTML onLoad event.

HTML code
        
        
        
          first2
        
        
        
         
           
              
            My Accounts

```
        <div class="MyMainSavings">
            <div class="MyMainSavingsTop">
                <table class="MyMainSavingsTop">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <td></td>
                </table>
                <div class="InterestRate">

                </div>
                <div class="regular">Regular</div>
            </div>
            <div class="MyMainSavingsBottom">
                <table class="tablebottom">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>

                        <td class="right"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="right"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="right"></td>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="MyEverydayExpenses">
            <div class="MyEverydayExpensesTop">
                <table class="MyEverydayExpensesTop">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <td></td>
                </table>
                <div class=".InterestRate">
                    <p></p>
                </div>
                <div class="regular">Regular</div>
            </div>
            <div class="MyEverydayExpensesBottom">
                <table class="tablebottom">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="right"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="right"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="right"></td>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="MyDeposit">
            <div class="MyDepositTop">
                <table class="MyDepositTop">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <td></td>
                </table>
                <div class=".InterestRate"></div>
                <div class="regular">Regular</div>
            </div>
            <div class="MyDepositBottom">
                <table class="tablebottom">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="right"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="right"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="right"></td>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="FavDeposit">
            <div class="FavDepositTop">
                <table class="FavDepositTop">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <td></td>
                </table>
                <div class=".InterestRate"></div>
                <div class="regular">Regular</div>
            </div>
            <div class="FavDepositBottom">
                <table class="tablebottom">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="right"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="right"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="right"></td>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="RightSection">
        <div class="RightSectionTopLeft">I Owe (from 3 Accounts)</div>
        <div class="RightSectionTopRight">-USD 33,4500.00</div>
        <div class="HomeLoan">
            <div class="HomeLoanTop">
                <table class="HomeLoanTop">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <td></td>
                </table>
                <div class=".InterestRate"></div>
                <div class="regular">Regular</div>
            </div>
            <div class="HomeLoanBottom">
                <table class="tablebottom">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="right"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="right"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="right"></td>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Ruby">
            <div class="RubyTop">
                <table class="RubyTop">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <td></td>
                </table>
                <div class=".InterestRate">

                </div>
                <div class="regular">Regular</div>
            </div>
            <div class="RubyBottom">
                <table class="tablebottom">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="right"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="right"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="right"></td>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="MyOverdraft">
            <div class="MyOverdraftTop">
                <table class="MyOverdraftTop">
                    <tr>
                        <td>MyOverdraft</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <td></td>
                </table>
                <div class=".InterestRate">

                </div>
                <div class="regular"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="MyOverdraftBottom">
                <table class="tablebottom">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="right"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="right"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="right"></td>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
      </body>
      </html>
```

JSON file

```
       var mainObject = {
          "Main": [{
          "I_Have": [{
          "MyMainSavings": {
             "MyMainSavingsTop": {
            "AccountName": "MyMainSavings",
            "AccountNumber": "x726",
            "Balance": "USD 5,600.00",
            "Rate": ""
        },
        "MyMainSavingsBottom": [{
            "Available": "Available",
            "Value": "$4329"
        }, {
            "Clear": "Clear",
            "Value": "$3456"
        }, {
            "Hold": "Hold",
            "Value": "$5000"
        }]
      }
      }, {
      "MyEverydayExpenses": {
        "MyEverydayExpensesTop": {
            "AccountName": "MyMainSavings",
            "AccountNumber": "x726",
            "Balance": "USD 600.00",
            "Rate": ""
        },
        "MyEverydayExpensesBottom": [{
            "Available": "Available",
            "Value": "$4329"
        }, {
            "Clear": "Clear",
            "Value": "$3456"
        }, {
            "Hold": "Hold",
            "Value": "$7300"
        }]
      }
      }, {
       "FavDeposit": {
        "FavDepositTop": {
            "AccountName": "MyMainSavings",
            "AccountNumber": "x726",
            "Balance": "USD 5,000.00",
            "Rate": "@4.5%"
        },
        "FavDepositBottom": [{
            "MaturityValue": "Maturity Value",
            "Value": "$4009"
        }, {
            "Term": "Term",
            "Value": "$1156"
        }, {
            "MaturesOn": "Matures On",
            "Value": "$5000"
        }]
      }
       }, {
      "MyDeposit": {
        "MyDepositTop": {
            "AccountName": "MyMainSavings",
            "AccountNumber": "x726",
            "Balance": "USD 8,600.00",
            "Rate": "@4.5%"
        },
        "MyDepositBottom": [{
            "MaturityValue": "Maturity Value",
            "Value": "$4329"
        }, {
            "Term": "Term",
            "Value": "$3456"
        }, {
            "MaturesOn": "Matures On",
            "Value": "$5000"
        }]
       }
       }]
        }
```

[Image for refernce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8Yby.png)

The html code has data in it. Essentially the data from html file should be removed and only come from json. By data I mean textual values appearing on the page. eg abc - This must not be the case, abc should come from json.

So the MyMainSavings div is corresponding to the MyMainSavings object in json, then MyMainSavingsTop div is corresponding to MyMainSavingsTop in json, so I want to populate the data in its corresponding element div through javascript/jquery. In short elements of same name should find themselves in the html file.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an exact way.  Your data should be structured in a way that properly reflects the domain objects it represents.  Your html should be structured in a way that meets the end users requirements.  And in the middle the logic should map the model to the view, however is best done.